# Search replace query in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

How would I search and replace for multiple values in a database?

For example, if I want to search a table for all mentions of the words yellow, blue, and green and replace them all with "black", how would I do that at the same time, without having to do the query for each individual word?

I have table `wp_posts` and want this to search and replace everything in `post_content`.

What exactly would the command look like?

Thank you!

Comment: If this is a one-time thing, you’re probably done quicker by just dumping the table contents, do a search-and-replace on the .sql file in a text editor, and then upload it to the database again. (That’ll of course only work if you’re not replacing any words critical to the SQL syntax.)

Answer (score 0):

For a `single table` update

```
UPDATE `table_name`
 SET `field_name` = replace(same_field_name, 'unwanted_text', 'wanted_text')
```

From `multiple tables`-

If you want to edit from all tables, best way is to take the `dump` and then `find/replace` and upload it back.

And / or use arrays, to choose that the specified colors, should be the `unwanted text` and the black color should be the `wanted text`

Comment: Hi, I don't need multiple tables -- I need multiple values. So one table, one field, with tons of values I need searched and replaced as in the example provided. Dumping and find/replace would take too long as there are too many values to search for one by one and replace one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts
   SET post_content = REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                          REPLACE(post_content, 
                          'yellow', 'black'), 
                        'blue', 'black'), 
                      'green', 'black')
 WHERE post_content LIKE '%yellow%'
    OR post_content LIKE '%blue%'
    OR post_content LIKE '%green%'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ab6f/1)** demo

Answer (score 0):

It's worth noting that any search and replace you do, can't be done in pure SQL UPDATE statements in WordPress (or many other PHP CMSs) because they have the nasty habit of storing content using serialized PHP strings. JSON can be easily edited without concerning yourself with lengths.

Consequently, you're better off using a search replace plugin or script. There are a number of tools out there to help with this problem.

You have a plugin solution called `Better Search Replace`, or you can use the `WP CLI Search Replace` command, or the `Search Replace DB` script. All use the same algorithm, and all have their use cases and weaknesses and you should be aware of these before embarking on what can be a rather destructive operation on a database. Do backup first!